# com.apple.dt.SKAgent on Xcode 11.2.1 consuming all resources

Tags: debugging, macos-mojave, xcode11

Any thoughts why this process com.apple.dt.SKAgent (4321) is consuming all mac mini resources? My Macmini has 16gb and 1Tb SSD drive . And, Xcode 11.2.1 becomes very slow and hangs. I have two workspaces (client/server) open and debugging is a nightmare, and Debugger can't show call stack and variables!!! I'm on Mojave[image]

Answer (score 2):

There aren't too many levers to pull to fix this. My standard course of action, in order if the last doesn't work:

- `Product -> Clean Build Folder` from the menu
- restart Xcode
- restart computer

This usually fixes things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to turn off "Suggest coalitions while typing" in "Preferences" -> "Text Editing" -> "Editing".